# Adding a column based on values in another column Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a data set that contains numerators and denominators in different columns for several different metrics. These metrics are measures at different rates though. One is a ratio, one is a percent, and the remainder are per 1000. In order to pull these values into a matrix that has metric and month in the rows and location in the columns, I need to have the rates in the correct format calculated. I have a per 1, per 100, and per 100 column which has multiplied the rate accordingly, I just need to pick and choose the correct column based on metric code. I tried this, which is giving me an error. What should I do to fix this?

`TotalRate = if('Midas Table'[IndicatorCode] = "MRAR:4002AMOE",'Midas Table'[Rate Per 1], if('Midas Table'[IndicatorCode] = "CDBR:137", 'Midas Table'[Rate Per 100], IF('Midas Table'[IndicatorCode] = "CDBR:3177", 'Midas Table'[Rate Per 1000],  IF('Midas Table'[IndicatorCode] = "CDBR:3139", 'Midas Table'[Rate Per 1000], "ERROR"))))`

Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.